# Using Proxies within Program

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding, proxy, character-encoding

So currently I'm having trouble with how to set the instance of my program to use a different proxy for *all* Internet related tasks; and I'm also having an error that stating that it: `Failed to parse`.

Now with the error, I'm not quite sure on the correct approach to fix it since I'm pulling information out of a .dat file; though I believe it may be an encoding error.

Anyway, now with the proxies, I've looked at other posts and submissions for awhile now, though it's still not running properly. I also see posts relating to `urllib2` all the time . . . and that's not what I want.

This is basically what I'm trying proxy wise:

```
proxy = [ . . . ]
os.environ['https_proxy'] = 'http://' + proxy
```

And this is also the error that follows:

```
Failed to parse: x.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
```

Overall thanks for your help, I appreciate it.

Comment: Not sure how your program works, but the basic idea is that you have to pass proxy settings to all your modules/function calls which you are using to send HTTP requests to the outside world. I have done it with `requests` and `urllib2` and it is reasonably straightforward and well documented on the web.

Comment: I thought that if you set it with `requests` or `urllib2` that it would only apply to those modules; is that not the case?

Comment: That is the case. As far as I know there's no magic bullet that will change the proxy behavior of all modules/functions using network functionality. You have to pass the proxy config one by one.

Comment: Okay well that makes sense, though if I'm using a site's API, is it likely that I can configure the connection using `requests` or `urllib2`? That's what I'm trying to solve, which is why I was going for a program-wide proxy connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why I was receiving the error mentioned above is because: when retrieving the proxies from a .dat file, I wasn't checking for `'\n'` or `' '` (the `' '` is an example if your data includes spaces, though obviously proxy strings do not).

So an example would be to use `.strip` after your retrieved information; such as:

```
fileList = []
with open('[ . . . ].dat') as f:
    for line in f:
        fileList.append(line.strip('\n').strip(' '))
return fileList[x]
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there's no magic bullet to change proxy settings of a "whole program". You have to find out which modules you are using (or the module that some other module you are using directly is using - e.g. `pandas` uses `urllib2`) and pass the proxy configuration. Below are two examples of the most commonly used modules: `urllib2` and `requests`

Example of using proxies in `urllib2` (on a module level):

```
proxy  = {"http":"10.111.111.111:8080", "https":"10.111.111.222:8080"}
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.ProxyHandler(proxy))
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
resp = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.com')
```

Example of using proxies in `requests` (on the function call level):

```
proxy = {"http":"10.111.111.111:8080", "https":"10.111.111.222:8080"}
resp  = requests.get('http://www.google.com', proxies = proxy)
```

Comment: I understand that, though I'm trying to use a proxy within a specific request using a site's API; though all in all thank you for your help.